# YARD convention for "any" object as a parameter

Tags: ruby, yard

How to document a YARD parameter that could be of any type possible?

Is there a convention for it?

This is similar to `Any` type in TypeScript

```ruby
# @param [?] var1
def create_foo(var1)
  # var1 could be anything
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since almost every object in Ruby inherits behavior from the class `Object`, `# @param [Object] var1` seems like an appropriate choice.

A few examples from [rubygems/rubygems](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph.rb#:%7E:text=Object) and [lostisland/faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/main/lib/faraday/request.rb#:%7E:text=Object)

Comment: And of course, YARD itself is document using YARD. An example for `[Object]` can be found in [`Options#[]=`](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/blob/e21c9323bba88c841a917d0531281b90f27f2378/lib/yard/options.rb#L98)

Comment: `Kernel` doesn't inherit behavior from the `Object` class. Having `nil` as an option `# @param [Object, nil] var1` might be important for RubyMine users, it distinguishes nilable and not-nilable method arguments, but couldn't recognize that `nil` is `NilClass` which is inherited from `Object`.

Comment: I've reverted the removal of "almost" as instances of [`BasicObject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/BasicObject.html) do _not_ inherit from `Object`.

Comment: @Stefan While the mentioned objects `Kernel` (Module) and `BasicObject` (Class) do not directly "inherit" from `Object` they are `Object`s because everything is an `Object`. e.g. `BasicObject.is_a?(Object) #=> true`, `Kernel.is_a?(Object) #=> true`. Note the anonymous eigenclass (metaclass, singleton_class) of `BasicObject` does include `Object` in its ancestry  `BasicObject.singleton_class.ancestors #=> [#<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]`. Possibly for this reason documenting as `[Object]` is widely used and accepted.

Comment: @Yakov all arguments are "nilable" because arguments do not have a type. Not all methods handle `nil` as an argument but most methods do not handle a lot of objects as arguments.

Comment: @engineersmnky that's why I said _"**instances** of BasicObject"_, i.e. `Object === BasicObject.new #=> false`